# implementing virtual mode for a datagridview that is databound

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, virtualmode

A general question for advice on the implementation.

I've got a collection bound to a `datagridview`.

```
BindingList<Line> allLines = new BindingList<Line>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = allLines;
```

I want to implement `virtual mode` because the collection could contain millions of entries (`Line` objects) so I thought it may be quicker to only 'cache' or display a few entries that are needed at a time. Which is what I understand virtual mode to be for?

I've looked at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx

But I can't get it to work for a `datagridview` that is `databound`.

I can't specify the row count:

```
this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 20;
`RowCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control.`
```

EDIT: this link suggests I may have to remove the binding completely. Is this the case? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx

'If bound mode does not meet your performance needs, you can manage all your data in a custom cache through virtual-mode event handlers.'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use [DataGridView.VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx), then you're not expected to use bound data set. They atr opposites. So, you don't set `DataSource`, but just set the `RowCount` property and provide an event handler for [DataGridView.CellValueNeeded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded.aspx).

Besides you need to set `dataGridView.VirtualMode` property to `true` first, probably write in the designer. By default it's set to `false`, that's why you get an exception, saying you cannot set `RowCount`.

Probably you'll have to manually initialize grid's columns.

While refreshing your grid (say, on button click), you'll have to

```
dataGridView.RowCount = 0;
\\refresh your cache, where you store rows for the grid
\\...
dataGridView.RowCount = yourCache.Count;//or some other property, getting the number of cached rows.
```

The `CellValueNeeded` event will be fired for each column of each row, depending on the RowCount and the number of columns. You're expected to set `e.Value` with the value of the processed cell in your event handler depending on the `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex`.

So, for this to work you'll need at least to handle `CellValueNeeded`. If your DataGridView is readonly, others events are not necessary.

A more complete and consecutive overview is available at [Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx).

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the reply. I thought they supplemented one another. But the exception was self explanatory, virtual mode was already set to true.